# alterting the key word using in jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to run a query for autosearch options using jquery UI autocomplete using the code ,

```
$("#srchBox").autocomplete({
 source: "http://localhost:8080/cleo-primer/rest/elements/search?uid=1"
});
```

When I run it, it sends the query,  `GET http://192.168.2.243:8080/cleo-primer/rest/elements/search?uid=1&term=in`,

but the original query should be `GET http://192.168.2.243:8080/cleo-primer/rest/elements/search?uid=1&query=in`,

The part after query is the input that we type in searchbox..
Is it possible to change the word "term" to "query"??

Answer (score 3):

Change `callback` function and handle responses:

```
$("#srchBox").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.get('http://192.168.2.243:8080/cleo-primer/rest/elements/search', {
          query: request.term,
          uid: 1
        }, function(data) {
            // process data
        });
    }
}).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    $(ul).attr('id', 'search-autocomplete');
       return $("<li class=\""+item.type+"\"></li>")
       .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
       .append("<a href=\""+item.url+"\">"+item.title+"</a>").appendTo(ul);
};
```

Comment: the first answer worked...but after the update it is not sending proper request.. the code that wrked is  $.get('http://192.168.2.243:8080/cleo-primer/rest/elements/search', { uid: 1, query: request.term }, function(data) {
           
         });

Comment: Thanks.. wil check it in detail and giv u a response.. and I wanted to see how that .data append function worked.. but u deleted that..:(